# Filer and Multi-Tenant Problem (Postgres Schemas)

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-filer

We are experiencing a weird problem. We use Postgresql Schemas and uses request middleware to switch between different schemas.

Keep in mind that the Model -> Content Type ID links differ from schema to schema due to new models made after the first tenant was created.

When I restart UWSGI and then on Tenant 1 goto the Filer->Folder page in the admin then it works well. Now when I go to Tenant 2 then it seems that filer is trying to use the content type id of the File model in Tenant 1 to lookup the real instance class.

Could it be that the ctype_id is being cached somehow?